# How to set stack background colour?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistackview

I am working for iOS app using `swift` in `XCode`.
I need four clickable image views  at bottom of the view. I have adjusted those in `stack`. Now I want to give a background colour to whole stack. Is there any option for this?

Thank you for help :)

Comment: put it all in one view and give color to view

Comment: what do you mean by stack ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this – `UIStackView` is a non-drawing view, meaning that `drawRect()` is never called. Its background color is not set. You can place the stack view inside another UIView and set background color value of that view.